# Permission Linux Files

Tags: linux, directory, permissions, centos

I am new in Linux machine. I was zapping into various centOs scripts, and I was wondering if there is a way to modify files with different users without any "Permission Denied" error.
I tried to create a group and then assigned a certain number of users into it. But it doesn't work.

Could you just advise me the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user you are trying to edit the file with must have write access permissions to the file.

I would suggest you to read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) of `chmod` command:

> **chmod** changes the file mode bits of each given file according to mode, which can be either a symbolic representation of changes to make, or an octal number representing the bit pattern for the new mode bits.

Here are some examples that might help you :

```
chmod +rwx filename to add permissions.
chmod -rwx directoryname to remove permissions.
chmod +x filename to allow executable permissions.
chmod -wx filename to take out write and executable permissions.
```

Comment: I mean, I just need to set a specific group for a folder. So, all the users into that group, could modify that specific files without any problem.

For example, if I modify a file with the root account, another user could not do that.

So I need a way to insert more users into a single group and then set that group for a series of folder.

Comment: @xAspired, Please study users/group permissions here. https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html. You need to know `chmod` and `chown` for this purpose.